# Strange wires behind a plate in living room (red plastic sensor looking)

Tags: electrical, wiring, receptacle

I was removing all the wall plates from my living room walls prior to painting and found a set of wires I have never seen before. If the wires are useless I would like to patch the hole with plaster to minimize the number of wall plates I have. If they are important then I'll just keep the plate.

Both red plastic pieces are connected to a wire from each of the two 'main' wires. the rest of the wires are not connected to anything. They are housed in a metal box similar to an electrical outlet.

Does anyone know what these are? Are they important?

[image: Wire Picture]

Comment: Those red disc-things on the ends of the wires are [splices](http://www.cableorganizer.com/platinum-tools/telcom-splicing-connectors-and-tool.html?gclid=CMH_hv3T9s0CFYQkhgodR6sG8w&gcssku=PL-18111&ef_id=V4l2MAAAASC55C0A:20160715234800:s).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Those are telephone wires. Looks like the cabling is CAT3, but I can't quite tell from the picture. The "red sensor" things aren't sensors, they are just splicers that are connecting two runs together. Google for "red telephone splicer" and you'll get tons of pictures of similar ones, as well as instructions on how to use them.

Comment: Thank you! I do not think any reasonable human will ever require a wired telephone in the living room barring an apocalyptic event that renders all cellphones useless. I think I'll just remove the box and plaster them in forever.

Comment: Think it through before eliminating it, could be a good spot for a low-profile ceiling mounted router.

Comment: It's a 1 story house. Thanks for the tip though.

Answer (score 1):

Telephone wire. The red things are crimp splices.